# turtles and sines in python

Tags: python, trigonometry, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to plot a sine wave using turtles in python but I've got a problem, I'm using a while loop with goto statements to plot the wave but the y values in the goto are constant (although they do change, but just not in the goto) Why is this? Because the x is behaving well

```
import math
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()f
wn.bgcolor('lightblue')

fred = turtle.Turtle()

x = 0

while x < 360:
    y = math.sin(math.radians(x))
    print y
    fred.goto(x, y)
    x += 1

wn.exitonclick()
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not just too flat to see? `sin` goes from -1 to 1, whereas your x coordinates take a much larger range of values.

Comment: Thanks! It was exactly that, when I multiplied y with hundred I could see everything

Answer (score 0):

Your `y` is changing, but the change is too small to show up in your graph properly. If you were to `goto(x,y*100)` this would be more obvious:

```
import math
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor('lightblue')

fred = turtle.Turtle()

x = 0

while x < 360:
    y = math.sin(math.radians(x))
    print y*100
    fred.goto(x, y*100)
    x += 1

wn.exitonclick()
```

Comment: A minute too late :).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you *not* bend your data to fit your graphics environment, but rather bend your graphics environment to fit your data.  In Python turtle, we can do this somewhat with `setworldcoordinates()`:

```
from math import pi, sin as sine
from turtle import Screen, Turtle, Vec2D

wn = Screen()
wn.bgcolor('lightblue')
wn.setworldcoordinates(-pi, -2, 3 * pi, 2))

fred = Turtle()

x = 0

while x < 2 * pi:
    position = Vec2D(x, sine(x))
    fred.setheading(fred.towards(position))  # visual detail, arrow follows line
    fred.goto(position)
    x += 0.1

wn.exitonclick()
```

[image]